# CSS hidden and visible properties change all the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following website:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var executed = false;
  if (!executed) {
    document.getElementById("at").style.visibility = "visible";
    setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById("t-ground").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("ground").style.opacity = "0.3";
      setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("right-top").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("t-ground").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("ground").style.opacity = "1.0";
        document.getElementById("t-plant").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("hand").style.opacity = "0.3";
        setInterval(function() {
          document.getElementById("right-bot").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("hand").style.opacity = "1.0";
          document.getElementById("t-plant").style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("ab").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("t-animal").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("animal").style.opacity = "0.3";
          setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("left-bot").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("animal").style.opacity = "1.0";
            document.getElementById("t-animal").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("t-human").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("human").style.opacity = "0.3";
            setInterval(function() {
              document.getElementById("left-top").style.visibility = "visible";
              document.getElementById("t-human").style.visibility = "hidden";
              document.getElementById("human").style.opacity = "1.0";
              document.getElementById("logo-mid").style.display = "none";
              setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("about-text").style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById("text-div").style.overflowY = "scroll";
                document.getElementById("at").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("ab").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("right-top").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("right-bot").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("left-bot").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("left-top").style.visibility = "hidden";
                executed = true;
              }, 1725);
            }, 2125);
          }, 2125);
        }, 2125);
      }, 2125);
    }, 2125);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 1100px;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px dotted #747737;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}

#text-div {
  height: 496px;
  width: 450px;
  border-top: 1px solid #747737;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #747737;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.about-text {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 472px;
  display: none;
}

#title-fading-in {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

.image-text {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: -230px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.arrow-in-image {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: -230px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: 1s ease;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.arrow-right-left {
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.arrow-top-bottom-wrapper {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 125px;
}

.arrow-top-bottom {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

#left-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 125px;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#left-bot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 246px;
  left: 125px;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#right-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#right-bot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 246px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-top-bottom-wrapper">
    <img alt="top" class="arrow-top-bottom" id="at" src="images/top.png">
  </div>

  <div class="left relative">
    <img alt="Blue" id="human" class="image" src="images/blue.png">
    <img alt="left-top" id="left-top" src="images/left-top.png">
    <div class="image-text" id="t-human">
      Sit
    </div>

    <img alt="red" id="animal" class="image" src="images/red.png">
    <img alt="left-bot" id="left-bot" src="images/left-bot.png">
    <div class="image-text" id="t-animal">
      Dolor
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="left">

    <div id="text-div">
      <div class="about-text" id="about-text">
        <center>
          Some Text
        </center>
      </div>

      <img alt="logo mid" class="logo-mid" id="logo-mid" src="images/purple.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="left relative">
    <img alt="green" id="ground" class="image" src="images/green.jpg">
    <img alt="right-top" id="right-top" src="images/right-top.png">
    <div class="image-text" id="t-ground">
      Lorem
    </div>

    <img alt="yellow" id="hand" class="image" src="images/yellow.jpg">
    <img alt="right-bot" id="right-bot" src="images/right-bot.png">
    <div class="image-text" id="t-plant">
      Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="arrow-top-bottom-wrapper">
    <img alt="bot" class="arrow-top-bottom" id="ab" src="images/bot.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

For some reason after loading the site, the hidden and visible properties change all the time. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because you set interval that triggers visible and hidden repeatedly? And you var "executed" is useless

Comment: Because there're a lot of setInterval nested that changes these properties

Comment: But I need these setInterval functions because of design purposes. These elements shall only appear after these amounts of times... :-(

Comment: Idk what you want to do but you probably want setTimeout which executes the function after a certain amount of time. Set Interval will repeat every x ms.

Comment: @user5014677 wow thanks that was the answer already, do you wanna post it so I can accept it?

Comment: How does your brain not go, “wow this code looks absolutely terrible” when even looking at this? First of all, a lot of this should be done by assigning proper classes to the elements, so that your stylesheet can take over the actual formatting, instead of setting individual styles. If you make some moderately clever use of stuff like the descendant selector, this could reduce the amount of code necessary by a lot.

Comment: Posted as answer for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` will execute the function repeatedly every x ms. So Your functions are all repeated triggering between visible and hidden all the time.

Since you want to do it once you need to use `setTimeout` which will only trigger once after x ms.